# What is the best way to replace a line with multiple lines in python?

Tags: python, replace, split

I have a large file with some lines containing similar info. Here is an example:

```
1001,"""software"" Backdoor",CVE-0000-0001
```

Some lines, however contain multiple CVE's for the same id number separated by ~. Those look like this:

```
5005,NetBIOS Brute Force of Accounts,CVE-1999-0504~CVE-1999-0505~CVE-1999-0506~CVE-1999-0518
```

I want these lines to split into this format:

```
5005,NetBIOS Brute Force of Accounts,CVE-1999-0504
5005,NetBIOS Brute Force of Accounts,CVE-1999-0505
5005,NetBIOS Brute Force of Accounts,CVE-1999-0506
5005,NetBIOS Brute Force of Accounts,CVE-1999-0518
```

I know I need to use the replace() function, but am confused on how to split it into more than 2 lines. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here is the code I'm using now. For some reason, it prints out the correct result, but does it 3 times.

```
with open("filepath") as f:
    for line in f:
        s = line    
        if "~" in line:
            #s = '5005,NetBIOS Brute Force of Accounts,CVE-1999-0504~CVE-1999-0505~CVE-1999-0506~CVE-1999-0518'
            a = s.split(',')
            for i in a:
                if a[-1].startswith('CVE') is True:
                    for j in a[-1].split('~'):
                        print(','.join(a[:-1] + [j]))
        else:
            print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = '5005,NetBIOS Brute Force of Accounts,CVE-1999-0504~CVE-1999-0505~CVE-1999-0506~CVE-1999-0518'
s2 = '5005,NetBIOS Brute Force of Accounts,CVE-1999-0504'
lines = [s, s2]

for i in lines:
    a = i.split(',')
    if a[-1].startswith('CVE') is True:
        b = a[-1].split('~')
        if len(b) == 1:
            print(','.join(a[:-1] + b))
        else:
            for j in b:
                print(','.join(a[:-1] + [j]))
```

Comment: this works, but I'd like to assign the s variable to the line in a file so it can do this for multiple lines. Assigning s to line (s = line) prints out the result 3 seperate times for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: was looping over each item in the list, which there were 3, should work fine now

Comment: just spotted an error and updated, had j instead of b on the first print